# How do I get rid of commas showing in my text area?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm coding a little program to generate a list of groceries, the items are in the screen and when you click on the "+" button, that item goes into the text area and so on. The problem is that after the first item, they all start with a comma for some reason. I know this must be something very basic but I just can't seem to find the issue.

[An image of the program running, with the issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itDFF.png)

I have two components besides the main App component, GroceryItem and GroceryItems.

GroceryItem:

```
export const GroceryItem = (props) => {

return (
    <div className="grocery" >
        <button 
            type="button"
            id={props.name}
            value={props.name}
            onClick={() => props.clickHandler(props.name)}
        >+</button>
        <label htmlFor={props.name}>{props.name}</label>
    </div>
)
```

}

GroceryItems:

```
export const GroceryItems = () => {
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);


const clickHandler = (v) => {
    setItems(prevState => [...prevState, `${v}\n`]);
    console.log(typeof v)
}
return (
    <>
        <div className="groceryContainer" >
            {listaMercado.map((el, i) => (
                <GroceryItem  clickHandler={clickHandler} key={i} name={el} />
            ))}
        </div>
        <textarea style={{margin: "30px", width: "300px",height: "300px"}} value={items} readOnly /> 
    </>

)
```

}

I'm omitting the list because it's just unnecessary.

Comment: Your items are in an array, and by default when the array is converted to a string the items will be separated by commas.

Comment: thanks, I got it from your comment :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Pointy pointed out (nice), you've converted your array to a string so currently you are just displaying the contents of the array as a long string.

To format it without the commas you can use a regular expression to remove all instances of "," when passing your items into the `textarea` value:

```
<textarea style={{margin: "30px", width: "300px", height: "300px"}} value={items.replace (/,/g, "")} readOnly />
```

If you're not familar with regex theres also this solution too:

```
items.split(",").join("")
```